# POST-запрос через Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Нужно отправить POST-запрос такой структуры через Jersey.client:

```
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<upload URL>">
     <input type="file" name="pic1" accept="image/*" />
     <input type="submit" />
     </form>
```

На этот код сервер ругается:

```
        Form form = new Form();
        form.add("input type", "file");
        form.add("name", "D-jlcp7yl6w");
        form.add("accept", "http://cs628824.vk.me/v628824012/10007/");
        form.add("input type", "submit");

        ClientResponse response = resource1
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

Ответ от сервера:

```
 {"error_msg":"one.image.server.upload.ContentUploadServerException: BAD_REQUEST","error_code":"4","error_data":"BAD_REQUEST"}
```

Я в этом деле новичок, буду очень признателен если подскажите как правильно.

Comment: Каким конкретно образом "сервер ругается"? Что приходит в ответ? И приходит ли? Есть ли сообщения об ошибках в консоли? Если есть, то какие?

Comment: И почему вы решили, что посредством этого кода вы сможете загрузить файл на сервер (если вы действительно собирались это сделать этим кодом)? Это делается как-то так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859956/jersey-image-upload-client